# Python Tkinter Slider

Tags: python, tkinter, slider

In this game the player starts with 100 coins to gamble in the slots. I've been trying to figure out a way to have a slider instead for people to slide up to a max of say 100 or slide down to a minimum of say 10. With the user being about to pick an amount in there. Either that or I'd need to change it to a text input with a min and max at still 10-100.

However I've been struggling to get something along the lines to work in this code. In a previous program I had a working slider so I know it was do able however my attempts to get it working here have been unsuccessful. Any ideas?

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

intro = """Panther's Den Slot Machine.


Welcome to my den!

You can win by rolling Ocelots, Jaguars, Boas, Caimans, Macaws or Tapirs.
You can also with big with three Ibis.

You'll lose a coin for anything else, and if you roll three Scorpions say good bye to 500 coins

Good luck kit!"""



root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("700x500")
root.title("Slot Machine")
root.configure(background='seagreen')

INIT_STAKE = 100
ITEMS = ["OCELOT", "MACAW", "JAGUAR", "IBIS", "CAIMAN", "BOA", "SCORPION", "TAPIR", "CONDOR", "BAMBOO", "FROG"]

first = None
second = None
third = None
stake = INIT_STAKE

nameLabel = tk.Label(root, text="PANTHER DEN", font=('Cambria', 60))
nameLabel.pack()
lbl = tk.Label(root, text=intro, background='seagreen', font=('Cambria', 12))
lbl.pack()
lbl2 = tk.Label(root, text=stake)
lbl2.pack()

def play():
    global first, second, third
    first = spin()
    second = spin()
    third = spin()
    score()

def quit_play():
    lbl.config(text="Game has ended. You won a total of " + str(stake) + " coins")

def spin():
    randomnumber = random.randint(0, 10)
    return ITEMS[randomnumber]

def score():
    global stake, first, second, third
    if((first == "OCELOT") and (second != "MACAW")):
        win = 5
    elif((first == "JAGUAR") and (second == "JAGUAR") and (third != "JAGUAR")):
        win = 8
    elif((first == "BOA") and (second == "BOA") and (third == "BOA")):
        win = 10
    elif((first == "CAIMAN") and (second == "CAIMAN") and ((third == "CAIMAN") or (third == "BOA"))):
        win = 8
    elif((first == "MACAW") and (second == "IBIS") and ((third == "MACAW"))):
        win = 15
    elif((first == "TAPIR") and (second == "TAPIR") and ((third == "TAPIR"))):
        win = 20
    elif((first == "IBIS") and (second == "IBIS") and (third == "IBIS")):
        win = 300
    elif((first == "SCORPION") and (second == "SCORPION") and (third == "SCORPION")):
        win = -500
    else:
        win = -1

    stake += win

    if(win > 0):
        lbl.config(text="{}\t{}\t{} -- You win {} Coins".format(first, second, third, win))
        lbl2.config(text=stake)
    else:
        lbl.config(text="{}\t{}\t{} -- You lose".format(first, second, third))
        lbl2.config(text=stake)

tk.Button(root, text="Play", command=play).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Quit", command=quit_play).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command=quit).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where is the slider code that you are struggling with?

Comment: It was a part of a temperature converter (C to F) to slide up and down to convert. 
        #creates a scale to use
        self.temp_scale = Scale(self.converter_frame,
                                from_=-50,
                                to= 120,
                                orient=HORIZONTAL,
                                length=200,
                                bg=background_color)
        self.temp_scale.grid(row=2,
                             columnspan=3,
                             padx=20,
                             pady=20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to add a slider that sets a bet value, via a command - here I used a global because your entire program is based on this, but you could encapsulate this in a class.

Then use this bet value to adjust the win/lose amounts.

The code here under reflects that. (you could easily add some controls that avoid bets that would set the player's funds negative, or limit the value of the bets to a % of the available funds).

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

intro = """Panther's Den Slot Machine.


Welcome to my den!

You can win by rolling Ocelots, Jaguars, Boas, Caimans, Macaws or Tapirs.
You can also with big with three Ibis.

You'll lose a coin for anything else, and if you roll three Scorpions say good bye to 500 coins

Good luck kit!"""


def play():
    global first, second, third
    first = spin()
    second = spin()
    third = spin()
    score()

def quit_play():
    lbl.config(text="Game has ended. You won a total of " + str(stake) + " coins")

def spin():
    randomnumber = random.randint(0, 10)
    return ITEMS[randomnumber]

def score():
    global stake, first, second, third
    if((first == "OCELOT") and (second != "MACAW")):
        win = 5 * bet
    elif((first == "JAGUAR") and (second == "JAGUAR") and (third != "JAGUAR")):
        win = 8 * bet
    elif((first == "BOA") and (second == "BOA") and (third == "BOA")):
        win = 10 * bet
    elif((first == "CAIMAN") and (second == "CAIMAN") and ((third == "CAIMAN") or (third == "BOA"))):
        win = 8 * bet
    elif((first == "MACAW") and (second == "IBIS") and ((third == "MACAW"))):
        win = 15 * bet
    elif((first == "TAPIR") and (second == "TAPIR") and ((third == "TAPIR"))):
        win = 20 * bet
    elif((first == "IBIS") and (second == "IBIS") and (third == "IBIS")):
        win = 300 * bet
    elif((first == "SCORPION") and (second == "SCORPION") and (third == "SCORPION")):
        win = -500 * bet
    else:
        win = -1 * bet

    stake += win

    if(win > 0):
        lbl.config(text="{}\t{}\t{} -- You win {} Coins".format(first, second, third, win))
        lbl2.config(text=stake)
    else:
        lbl.config(text="{}\t{}\t{} -- You lose".format(first, second, third))
        lbl2.config(text=stake)

def set_bet(value):
    global bet
    bet = int(value)
    lbl2.config(text=str(bet))    


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("700x500")
root.title("Slot Machine")
root.configure(background='seagreen')

INIT_STAKE = 100
ITEMS = ["OCELOT", "MACAW", "JAGUAR", "IBIS", "CAIMAN", "BOA", "SCORPION", "TAPIR", "CONDOR", "BAMBOO", "FROG"]

first = None
second = None
third = None
stake = INIT_STAKE

nameLabel = tk.Label(root, text="PANTHER DEN", font=('Cambria', 60))
nameLabel.pack()
lbl = tk.Label(root, text=intro, background='seagreen', font=('Cambria', 12))
lbl.pack()
lbl2 = tk.Label(root, text=stake)
lbl2.pack()

tk.Button(root, text="Play", command=play).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Quit", command=quit_play).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command=quit).pack()

bet = 0

bet_scale = tk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=stake, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=200, bg='violet', command=set_bet)
bet_scale.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It adds a slider at the bottom I can move around but it doesn't actually effect the bet amount. That is still set at 100. I need the slider to change his amount sorry. Having it in a class might help better?

Comment: You are very welcomed! It is actually setting the bet correctly; what was missing was the update of the label showing the bet, not the setting of the bet value itself. I added that for you!